# How to get spring boot application jar parent folder path dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot web application which I run using **java -jar application.jar**. I need to get the jar parent folder path dynamically from the code. How can I accomplish that?

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file), but without success.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. In this case,  you mention that you tried a solution but what is your error or what is your basic implementation.

Comment: If I from the terminal with **java -jar application.jar** the code presented on that questtion will return null. I'll put the code here: 

`MyCustomClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();`

If I run the application using Spring Tools Suit IDE play button, the result of this code will be: 

`/D:/arquivos/repositorio/myapp/trunk/target/classes/`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well, what have worked for me was an adaptation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837263/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-the-currently-executing-jar-file-is-in).
The code is:

> if you run using java -jar myapp.jar dirtyPath will be something close
>   to this: jar:file:/D:/arquivos/repositorio/myapp/trunk/target/myapp-1.0.3-RELEASE.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/br/com/cancastilho/service.
>       Or if you run from Spring Tools Suit, something like this:
>       file:/D:/arquivos/repositorio/myapp/trunk/target/classes/br/com/cancastilho/service

```
public String getParentDirectoryFromJar() {
    String dirtyPath = getClass().getResource("").toString();
    String jarPath = dirtyPath.replaceAll("^.*file:/", ""); //removes file:/ and everything before it
    jarPath = jarPath.replaceAll("jar!.*", "jar"); //removes everything after .jar, if .jar exists in dirtyPath
    jarPath = jarPath.replaceAll("%20", " "); //necessary if path has spaces within
    if (!jarPath.endsWith(".jar")) { // this is needed if you plan to run the app using Spring Tools Suit play button. 
        jarPath = jarPath.replaceAll("/classes/.*", "/classes/");
    }
    String directoryPath = Paths.get(jarPath).getParent().toString(); //Paths - from java 8
    return directoryPath;
}
```

EDIT:

Actually, if your using spring boot, you could just use the [ApplicationHome](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationHome.html) class like this:

```
ApplicationHome home = new ApplicationHome(MyMainSpringBootApplication.class);
home.getDir();    // returns the folder where the jar is. This is what I wanted.
home.getSource(); // returns the jar absolute path.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    File file = new File(".");
    logger.debug(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

This worked for me to get the path where my jar is running, I hope this is what you are expecting.

Comment: This code will return the folder path where I issued the java -jar command.
If I run it from my target folder:

   cd D:\arquivos\repositorio\myapp\trunk\target
   java -jar application.jar


I'll get this result:
`D:\arquivos\repositorio\myapp\trunk\target\.`

If I run it from an outside folder, let's say:

   cd D:\arquivos\repositorio\myapp\trunk\
   java -jar target\application.jar


I'll get: `D:\arquivos\repositorio\myapp\trunk\.`

It partially solves my problem. Is there a way to find the path even if I issue the command from another external folder?

Comment: Will this not keep on creating new files of . everytime the script is run?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public static String getParentRealPath(URI uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    if (!"jar".equals(uri.getScheme()))
        return new File(uri).getParent();
    do {
        uri = new URI(uri.getSchemeSpecificPart());
    } while ("jar".equals(uri.getScheme()));
    File file = new File(uri);
    do {
        while (!file.getName().endsWith(".jar!"))
            file = file.getParentFile();
        String path = file.toURI().toString();
        uri = new URI(path.substring(0, path.length() - 1));
        file = new File(uri);
    } while (!file.exists());
    return file.getParent();
}

URI uri = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI();
System.out.println(getParentRealPath(uri));
```