# How can I retrieve the directory containing the executed jar file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, executable-jar

I am working on a Spring Boot application runned as executable jar. In my code I am trying to retrieve the folder where is located the runned jar file. But I am finding some difficulties. I have done in this way:

```
File jarFile = new File(BeanConfig.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
String jarFolder = jarFile.getParentFile().getPath();
System.out.println("FOLDER: " + jarFolder);
```

The problem is that, doing in this way, the printed output is something like this:

```
FOLDER: file:/home/andrea/git/notartel-api-batch/target/UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF
```

And this is not what I need because I need the path of the directory containing my jar file that int this case is this one: **/home/andrea/git/notartel-api-batch/target/**

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this behavior in order to retrieve the path of the directory containing my jar file?

Comment: You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657181/how-to-get-spring-boot-application-jar-parent-folder-path-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

In a Spring Boot application you can do this:

```
ApplicationHome applicationHome = new ApplicationHome(MySpringBootApp.class);
String jarFolder = applicationHome.getDir().getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println("FOLDER: " + jarFolder);
```

Comment: Great! Only one thing getDir() returns a File not a String

Comment: tnx, now calling .getAbsolutePath() on the file

Answer (score 0):

```
ApplicationHome home = new ApplicationHome(MyMainSpringBootApplication.class);
home.getDir();    // returns the folder where the jar is.
home.getSource(); // returns the jar absolute path.
```